# Python GUI App Distribution: written in wxPython, TKinter or QT

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pyqt, tkinter

My question is about the easiness of distributing the GUI app across the platforms (Mac/Linux/Windows), and I want to know the one that makes the user's job easiest.

My current understanding is that Tkinter app is the easiest for the users (to install) because as long as the user has installed a Python in her box, my application should be ready to run on that box.

For GUI app written in wxPython or pyQT, the user needs to install wxWidget or QT in her box first, which is an extra step, and then install my GUI app. (But my Ubuntu box seems to have the wxWidget libraries and QT libraries installed by default, is that a norm or just Ubuntu distro is more friendly to users? I guess Windows and Mac probably does not provide them by defualt, ie. the users need to download and install them as an extra step)

Comment: There's no guarantee that tkinter will be available just because Python is. It's an extension module, and so can be split out into a separate package. The Mandriva Linux distribution does this, and there are probably others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running Ubuntu, PyQt will be installed by default. Most linux distros will have one of  PyGtk or PyQt installed by default. WxPython was most likely installed in your Ubuntu box as a dependency for some other package in your system.

If your target market is Linux, you can just create a deb or rpm package and that'll take care of the dependencies for your application.

For Windows and Mac(and even Linux if you're so inclined) you could bundle the python interpreter with your application and its libraries into a native executable format such
as .exe, .dmg or .elf using libraries like `cx_freeze`, `py2exe` and `py2app`. Once this is done, your user will not have to install `python` or any of your libraries.

Comment: [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is multiplatform and supports many 3rd party libraries such as PyQt, wxPython out-of-the-box

Answer (score 4):

Tkinter is the only one that's included with Python. wxPython and pyQT need both the wxWindows or QT libraries *and* the wxPython or pyQT libraries to be installed on the system.

However, Tk does not look very nice. If you're already making the user install Python, you could just as well have them install the libraries too. (Or maybe include an installer or something.)

Comment: I think the comment about the look of Tk is out of place here. The question isn't about which toolkit to choose, but what the deployment options are. Plus, the look of Tk is highly subjective, so it detracts from the answer, IMO.

Comment: Besides, with the new ttk sub-library of Tkinter (available in Python 2.7+ or at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk), you can make Tkinter apps look pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

If the app is going to be cross-platform I would suggest `WxWidgets` (`wxpython`). I have used it several times and it has never been a problem.

Nevertheless, you should create different installers for Windows, Mac and Linux. In Linux, use `.deb` or `.rpm` to take care of dependencies.

In Windows, I've always used `py2exe` to create an `exe` file. `Py2exe` works by attaching the python interpreter and the needed libraries, in this case `wxWidgets`.

Check this link for more information: http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: I think the comment about choosing wxWidgets is out of place here. The question isn't about which toolkit is best, it's about deployment options. Saying "I choose X" when the question isn't about choosing "X" may invite up-votes and down-votes simply because somebody likes or dislikes wxPython. I think the question would be better if you stuck to the topic of deployment. Unless, however, you're specifically saying that wxPython is easier to deploy, in which case you should explain why.